# What part of “Coq: default values for vectors” is on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

We raised the issue of [scope limits for proof assistants](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/scope-limits-on-proof-assistants-e-g-coq) a while ago, and didn't come to a conclusion. It's been two years, what does the community think now?

More specifically, is the question [Coq: default values for vectors](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24496/coq-default-values-for-vectors) on-topic? It combines several aspects:

- language design with a strong theoretic underpinning (“Was this built this way to keep the type small”)
- type theory — although not explicitly formulated in the question, the answer would involve some
- library design
- programming in a proof assistant language

Comment: I actually read the quote you give in bullet one as "language design with focus on compiler/runtime programming/efficiency".

Comment: @Raphael Hmmm, I guess you're right. I hadn't cottoned on “the memory sense” — I don't know what that means, but it seems to mean *not* the sense of small type in Coq's type theory.

Answer (score 5):

That question was pretty clearly a Coq-specific question: defining a "get n-th" function in Coq will be all but useless to a beginner in, say, Agda. *How does pattern matching work in dependently typed languages* would be a much better question.

Also: the Coq mailing list is really good at answering Coq-specific questions, and is appropriate, so I don't see why we should bother (though I'm sure many people here contribute to both).